# How to learn optimal unknown constants (hyperparameters) in a function

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent, hyperparameter

I have a function that takes 2 known values as input, as well as 8 unknown constants.

Lets call it  $f(X, k) = y$ where each index $i$ of $X$ is a vector of the 2 input values

$k$ is a vector of the unknown constants.

$y$ is a vector of known outputs ($y^{(i)}$ is a single output value)

Given a dataset containing with pairs of $X^{(i)}, y^{(i)}$ how do I learn the values of $k$ that minimize the difference between $f(X^{(i)}, k)$ and $y^{(i)}$ across this dataset.

It seems that I should be minimizing the cost function of the means squared error between $f(X, k)$ and $y$:

$$
\frac{1}{2m} \sum_{i=1}^m(f(X^{(i)}, k) - y^{(i)})^2
$$

This is similar to a gradient descent, however my equation is not in correct form.

One thing that comes to mind is performing grid search across the possible values of k.

What are some other methods to do this? The output I want is the vector k that minimizes that function.

Comment: Do you know the functional form of $f$?  Or is it a black box, and all you have are (input, output) pairs?

Comment: @jbowman Yes, I know the functional form of $f$. I also know some constraints on the values of $k$, but I am also interested in answers that do not have any knowledge of constraints on $k$.

Comment: What you (in all probability) want is an implementation of the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm for solving nonlinear least squares problems.  The one in the R package `minpack.lm` (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/minpack.lm/minpack.lm.pdf) allows for constraints as well.